# Dynamically add routes

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

I have a tab component service with a method that sets the tabs. Each tab has a route to a separate component.

```
setTabs(components: any[]) {

        // components: [{ title: 'Foo bar', path: 'foo-component', component: FooComponent },
        // { title: 'Whoo bar', path: 'whoo-component', component: WhooComponent }]

        for (let i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {
            let component = components[i];
            this.addTab(component);
            this._router.config.push({path: component.path, component: component.component});
        }


        // << DOESNT RESET ROUTE, WHY?? >>
        this._router.resetConfig(this._router.config);
    }
```

How can I dynamically add routes?

Comment: What does "not working mean exactly"?

Comment: I think you should create the routes array and then use `_router.resetConfig(routes)` instead of `this._router.config.push(...)`

Comment: I keep getting an error saying: 

Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'user/someone/showcase' ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'user/someone/showcase'

Comment: Perhaps you should first try the routes configuration by adding it statically, and when they work add them dynamically. Perhaps you instead want `_router.root.resetConfig(routes)`.